# How can I make Core Plot to show an x-axis label for each point in time?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

Apart from the issue I am trying to fix atm, I would like to know how I can make the x-axis labels to draw wherever there is a point drawn. As you can see on the screenshot there are three points in time. So instead of the label "1/10/54' (yes that is year 54) floating nowhere, I want three labels, one below each point. 
(Note the 3 points are only for illustration, needs to be expandable.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the spacing between the labels will be irregular like your sample screenshot, you'll want to change the axis labeling policy to `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` or `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyLocationsProvided`. Both policies require you to provide the tick locations. The first policy also requires you to make custom labels that don't have to be at the same locations as the tick marks while the second will automatically make labels at each tick location using the standard label formatter.

Comment: Thx Eric, looking at your answers, you look like a CP expert. Any idea how I can take away the padding from the hostedViewController, the space between the edge of the screen and the graph view?

Comment: `graph.paddingLeft = 0.0;`, `graph.paddingTop = 0.0;`, etc.